How can I grep to include the surrounding lines?
I'm trying to grep a specific block of text consisting of 6 lines from a large log file.
For example, the file may contain content like this:
...
...

Warning-[SDFCOM_CFIIS] Cannot find instance in scope
/home/ncdb/BASELINES/PROJECT/func/max.hacked.sdf.gz 245
module: TOP, " instance test.u_cpu"
SDF Warning: Cannot find instance
u_top.u_BLK.udphy_cpre
in scope test.u_top


Warning-[SDFCOM_CFIIS] Cannot find instance in scope
/home/ncdb/BASELINES/PROJECT/func/max.hacked.sdf.gz 246
module: TOP, " instance test.u_cpu"
SDF Warning: Cannot find instance
u_top.u_BLK.udphy_core
in scope test.u_top


Warning-[SDFCOM_CFIIS] Cannot find instance in scope
/home/ncdb/BASELINES/PROJECT/func/max.hacked.sdf.gz 246
module: TOP, " instance test.u_cpu"
SDF Warning: Cannot find instance
u_top.u_BLK.udphy_core
in scope test.u_top
...
...

When I try to grep using :grep SDFCOM_CFIIS my_big_huge.log, it only returns the lines containing SDFCOM_CFIIS, like this:
Warning-[SDFCOM_CFIIS] Cannot find instance in scope
Warning-[SDFCOM_CFIIS] Cannot find instance in scope
Warning-[SDFCOM_CFIIS] Cannot find instance in scope
Warning-[SDFCOM_CFIIS] Cannot find instance in scope
Warning-[SDFCOM_CFIIS] Cannot find instance in scope
Warning-[SDFCOM_CFIIS] Cannot find instance in scope
Warning-[SDFCOM_CFIIS] Cannot find instance in scope
Warning-[SDFCOM_CFIIS] Cannot find instance in scope
...

How can I grep to include the surrounding lines? I want to grep like
Warning-[SDFCOM_CFIIS] Cannot find instance in scope
/home/ncdb/BASELINES/PROJECT/func/max.hacked.sdf.gz 246
module: TOP, " instance test.u_cpu"
SDF Warning: Cannot find instance
u_top.u_BLK.udphy_core
in scope test.u_top

Warning-[SDFCOM_CFIIS] Cannot find instance in scope
/home/ncdb/BASELINES/PROJECT/func/max.hacked.sdf.gz 246
module: TOP, " instance test.u_cpu"
SDF Warning: Cannot find instance
u_top.u_BLK.udphy_core
in scope test.u_top

Warning-[SDFCOM_CFIIS] Cannot find instance in scope
/home/ncdb/BASELINES/PROJECT/func/max.hacked.sdf.gz 246
module: TOP, " instance test.u_cpu"
SDF Warning: Cannot find instance
u_top.u_BLK.udphy_core
in scope test.u_top

from a source log file.

The answer depends on your value of the 'grepprg' option.
By default, Vim uses your standard system grep on Unix
systems.
See :help 'grepprg' for reference and :set grepprg? to see whatever you use.
Consequently, grep's rules for context apply.
Remember that context lines are as easy as ABC (almost as if it's supposed to be a mnemonic):

-A number of lines After
-B number of lines Before
or -C for the number of Context lines (before and after).

Or take a look at man grep, section
Context Line Control.
The Vim command to add 6 lines after "SDFCOM_CIIS" is:
:grep -A6 SDFCOM_CFIIS my_big_huge.log

But what if the 'grepprg' option is set to something else?
Don't worry.
Most grep-like programs support the -A, -B, and -C options.
The notable exception is MS DOS' findstr command which is ... different.
Personally, I never went down that rabbit hole.
Luckily, Git-Bash comes with good ol' grep.

I'm always struggling with whether -A/-B stand for above/below or after/before. Will probably need to settle for -C to get that pain out of my brain :-)

@Hans-MartinMosner thank you for spreading your mental virus :-)

You can do it in plain vim (or vi):
:g/SDFCOM_CFIIS/p 6

See the documentation for the :g and :p ex commands. p 6 means to print 6 lines from the current line.  You could replace it with .,.+5p for a purer ed approach.
However, this will not add entries to the quick fix list.  (Maybe you could use :caddexpr?)

In fact, this suggests printf '%s\n' 'g/pat/.,+6p' q | ed -s log > results, although that’s not too different from grep -A6 pat log > results in the end.

Always nice to see somebody using :g/re/p

Another option is to write the matches + 6 lines to a temporary file. Something like:
:grep pat log
:cdo .,+6write >>search-results
:edit search-results

This should work even if your grepprg doesn’t support the otherwise excellent context options.

The CtrlSF plugin extends the standard grep functionality of Vim.
It introduces the :CtrlSF command.
You could achieve what you intends to have with:
:CtrlSF -B 0 -A 5 /Warning-[SDFCOM_CFIIS]/

And then switch to context mode using the M key.
Remark: The answer of @Friedrich is more standard the CtrlSF plugin value is more in the possibility to edit the result of the grep.

Thank you for the praise. You don't have to do that.

@Friedrich, we have to guide the user toward the best solution which is the most standard that fit the bill. I could also have delete mine looking at yours but I believe it also make sense to give visibility to good plugins.

Thank you once more. This would be a terribly dull place if every question only had one answer. I'm glad you didn't delete your answer.
